# Correctly display plotted lines in a Two State Model graph

Tags: python, math

The problem I'm having is that the plotted lines on my graph aren't displaying correctly because I don't exactly know how to modify the equation to get the desired output. The graph is generated using matplotlibs.

The plotted lines I have right now are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEi91.png).

The formulas im using are:

```py
XF = AfXf(i) + Bfe(i)
XS = AsXs(i) + Bse(i)
Xnet = Xf(i) + Xs(i)
E = trials(i) - Xnet(i)
```

The code that I used to generate the output seen in the picture is here:

```py
    As = 0.998
    Bs = 0.049
    Af = 0.597
    Bf = 0.227

    # Trial numbers
    baseline_trials = 25
    rotation_trials = 75
    reverse_rotation_trials = 10
    washout_trials = 40

    # Create an array of labels for each trial, representing the type of trial (full num of trials)
    trials = np.concatenate((np.zeros(baseline_trials), np.ones(
    rotation_trials), np.ones(reverse_rotation_trials) * -1, np.zeros(washout_trials)))

    # Create arrays to store variables for each trial
    E = np.zeros_like(trials)
    XS = np.zeros_like(trials)
    XF = np.zeros_like(trials)
    Xnet = np.zeros_like(trials)

    for i in range(len(trials) - 1):
        # Calculate error
        E[i] = trials[i] - Xnet[i]

        # Update slow and fast states
        XS[i + 1] = As * XS[i] + Bs * E[i]
        XF[i + 1] = Af * XF[i] + Bf * E[i]

        # Calculate net adaptation
        Xnet[i + 1] = XS[i + 1] + XF[i + 1]
```

So far, the only thing that I've thought to try out was to change the index values of XS, XF and Xnet. That hasn't gotten me very far. The output im looking for is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNJ1I.png).